# how to show the multiple images in one

Tags: c#

I need to show multiple images in one window and directly select one image for maximize,minimize and close it but not reflect to other images
 please give me some suggestion to do this task  in c# .net /C++ .net

Comment: You need to explain in much more detail what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Do you mean similar to how GIMP/Photoshop work?  You may want to look into something called "MDI", or simply create different modeless dialogs/windows for each image.  Are you using Window Forms, or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you should put all the images into datagrid and on click event send ImageUrl of selecred image onto another forms constructor in which that selected image wil be shown....

Answer (score 1):

From your (very vague) description (please add more information), I believe you want to look into creating new dialogs for each image, or using a [Multiple Document Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface).

- Window Forms: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/MDIApp.aspx
- WPF: http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

Note that if you want to use MDI in WPF, you'll have to do some extra work, because it isn't directly supported.  That's why I link to that library.

If there is an existing application who's design you like, and would like to replicate, please mention it.  That would help us get an idea of what you are trying to accomplish.